# Rearrange python list to avoid any position matches

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists list1 and list2. How would I rearrange list1 (without rearranging list2) so that there are no matches on any positions eg:

UNDESIRED: `list1 = [‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’]  list2 = [‘X’, ‘B’, ‘Z’]` as you can see the B is on the same position, 1, in both lists…so I would then like to rearrange list1 to `list1 = [‘B’, ‘A’, ‘C’]` or any other order where there are no positional matches with list2 WITHOUT rearranging list2

Comment: Have you tried something ? Can you add that to you post ?

Comment: There are some cases where it isn't possible to rearrange it the way you want, for example: if list2 was `['B','B','B]` There are also cases with multiple solutions

Comment: What's the underlying context for this question? What *problem do you hope to solve* by rearranging the list this way?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with the help of the *itertools* module. There may be better / more efficient mechanisms. Note that the *process()* function will return None when there is no possible solution.

```
import itertools

def process(L1, L2):
    for s in set(itertools.permutations(L1, len(L1))):
        if all([a != b for a, b in zip(s, L2)]):
            return s
    return None

list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = ['X', 'B', 'Z']

print(process(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import permutations

def diff(list1, list2):
    for item in permutations(list1, len(list1)):
        if all(map(lambda a, b: a!=b, item, list2)):
            return list(item)
    return None

list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = ['X', 'B', 'Z']

result = diff(list1, list2)
if result:
    print(result, 'vs', list2)
```

```py
['A', 'C', 'B'] vs ['X', 'B', 'Z']
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this piece of code - however, as noted above, there are many possible cases where this very solution may not work. In this very case, you can try this:

```
import random
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = ['X', 'B', 'Z']
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i == j in list2:
            while list1.index(i) == list2.index(j):
                list1.remove(i)
                z = len(list1)
                rand = random.choice(range(z))
                list1.insert(rand, i)
print(list1, list2)
```

Also, note that you use quite weird apostrophes inside the list: `‘` instead of `'` or `"`. AFAIK, Python won't be able to comprehend them correctly.

Comment: Agreed that this works for the OP's specific data but it's not a general solution. Changing 'C' to 'B' in *list1* will put your solution into an infinite loop

Comment: Never claimed it will be general, but your point is valid. I guess a better way can be to use import module, and generate random index depending of the `len(list1)`, and then apply `.insert()` method to it. I updated my solution to show what I mean.